# Shorten code that contains a sequence of 'null' tests

Tags: c#

Can I somehow connect two assignments to `temp` into one condition (with `&`) in the `if` statement?

```
node temp = new node();
temp = queue.Find(match => match.Check_node_state(element.state));
if (temp == null)
    temp = explored_nodes.Find(match => match.Check_node_state(element.state));
if (temp == null)
```

Comment: Possibly, but why would you want to shorten it?  It's very readable as it is.

Comment: Look at the `??` operator. It does what you want. If you put it on two lines, I think it could be readable enough.

Comment: Tip: Don't initialise `temp` to `new node()` on the first line then assign something else to it on the second.

Comment: @WaiHaLee I thought that at first, but he's basing his null checks off of it so needs to set it to something. It's a little strange though

Comment: @JoePhilllips - He **is** setting it to something, though. The first and second lines could be conflated to `node temp = queue.Find(match => match.Check_node_state(element.state));`

Comment: @WaiHaLee Oh yeah, I guess you're right

Answer (score 11):

You can chain the [null coalescing operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx).

```
node temp = queue.Find(match => match.Check_node_state(element.state))
            ?? explored_nodes.Find(match => match.Check_node_state(element.state))
            ?? someOtherFind()
            ?? anotherFind();

if (temp == null)
    throw new Exception("This thing really does not exist!");
```

Answer (score 5):

In C#, the operator you want is `??` which allows you to provide an alternate value in case the first is null. The statement would look something like this:

```
node temp = queue.Find(match => match.Check_node_state(element.state))
  ?? explored_nodes.Find(match => match.Check_node_state(element.state));
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you certainly can do:

```
if (queue.Find(match => match.Check_node_state(element.state)) == null &&
    explored_nodes.Find(match => match.Check_node_state(element.state)) == null)
```

But I don't see it as a *huge* improvement...

Note that you need to use `&&` instead of `&` to make the code equivalent because `&&` short-circuits, while `&` will evaluate *both* conditions even if the first is true.

Comment: Also because `&` is not a logical operator.

Comment: @dotNET [Yes it is](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c.aspx), for boolean arguments.  For integral arguments it is a bit-wise operator.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Any` to make code even more readable:

```
if (!queue.Any(match => match.Check_node_state(element.state)) &&
    !explored_nodes.Any(match => match.Check_node_state(element.state)))
```

Comment: You're assuming that `queue` and `explored_nodes` are collections that support Linq.